# Programmatically opening / showing Android System Settings screen from within Air Application

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I created a cross-platform mobile application using adobe air ( 18 ) 
The application uses the geolocation services on demand.
Now when the user turned off the services globally on his device, i get the

```
Geolocation.muted = true
```

In this case I show an Alert, telling the user to Turn on Geolocation services. 
Is there also a way to directly open the corresponding System Settings Preference page from within the Air application?

Comment: This can only be done by creating an ANE. In as3 alone there's no way.

Comment: ah, thank you. too bad.